# Linux tar files less than 3 months ago using date in filename

Tags: bash

In Linux I have files which filename is starting with date YYYYMMDD

```
20160201_001.pdf
20160110_002.pdf
20150201_003.pdf
20140201_004.pdf
```

I want to tar those files less than the following date range (not using mtime, but filename period)

```
date +'%Y%m' -d '4 months ago'  (201511)
```

Basically i want to do

```
files=($(find . -name filename< date +'%Y%m' -d '4 months ago'))
tar cvfz backup.tar.gz "${files[@]}"
```

The expected result of files being tar-ed:

```
20150201_003.pdf
20140201_004.pdf
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you need to do this recursively or will all files be in the same directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that date format, you could use string ordering in `awk`, such as:

```
files=( $(ls | awk -v d=$(date -d '4 months ago' +%Y%m%d_999.pdf) '$1<d {print;}') )
tar cvfz backup.tar.gz "${files[@]}"
```

The `awk` program reads input lines, and applies its rules to them. In this case it firstly gets invoked with variable `d` set as the clipping date expanded into a file name. Then, for each line it compares the first word (`$1`) with the clipping date (`d`) with respect to alphabetical order, and where the input is before the clip, it prints the line (otherwise not).

To clip month-wise, change `%d` to be `00` to exclude the month of four months ago, or `99` to include the month of four moths ago.

Comment: what is the awk and '$1<d {print;}' do?

Answer (score 1):

Please check this script as per your requirement. Hope this works for you. Change it according to your requirement

```
lines=`expr 0 + 0`
maxlines=`expr 0 + 100`
while [ 1 -le 5 ] ; do
     d=`date +%G%m%d`
     count=`ls -1 | grep $d |wc -l`
     c=`expr $count + 0`
     while [ $c -gt 0 ]; do
          file=`ls -1 | grep $d |tail -$c |head -1`
          searchFile=`grep $file tmp | head -1 | wc -l`
          searchFile=`expr $searchFile + 0`
          if [  $searchFile -eq 0 ]; then
               cp $file /home/avinash/f
               echo $file >>tmp
               lines=`expr $lines + 1`
          fi 
          c=`expr $c - 1`
     done     
     if [ $lines -gt $maxlines ]; then 
            k=`date +%G%m`
          grep $k tmp > t
          mv -f t tmp
          lines=`expr 0 + 0`
     fi     
done
```

This script will choose only the files for today date as per server time. This script is running in an infinite loop.

Thus whenever there is a new file in the directory it checks the file name, and if the name contains today date, it puts the file in `home/avinash/red` directory from where PI server picks it up for reading.

Please change the folder name according to your convenience. Now in the folder `/home/avinash` you need to keep a file called `temp` this file will contain only one word or any symbol say `hi`. The use of temp is to collect all file names that the script has already transferred to PI folder. Thus if script has transferred file say `ABC_20110725.txt` and `DEF_20110725.txt`, then `tmp` will have contents

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
$ files=( $(d=$(date +'%Y%m' -d '4 months ago'); 
          for f in *.pdf; do [[ "${f:0:6}" -le "$d" ]] && 
                             printf '%s\n' "$f"; done;) )
$ tar cvzf backup.tgz "${files[@]}"
20140201_004.pdf
20150201_003.pdf
```

#### Explanation

- `d=$(date +'%Y%m' -d '4 months ago')` : set the variable `$d` to the desired date.
- `for f in *.pdf; do ... ; done` : iterate over all `.pdf` files in the directory, saving each as `$f`.
- `[[ "${f:0:6}" -le "$d" ]]` : check if the 1st 6 characters of the file's name are smaller than or equal to the value of `$d`.
- `&& printf '%s\n' "$f"; done;` : if they are, print the file name.
- `files=( $( ... ) )` : save the output of the above in the array `$files`.

Note that this assumes that all your `pdf` file names start with at least 6 digits and will complain if they don't. You can make it more robust by iterating only over those pdf files that do:

```
for f in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*.pdf; do ...
```